# How to return integers from an array that are concatenating the values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, types, concatenation

I've been given the simple task of creating a tip calculator as follows:

John and his family went on a holiday and went to 3 different restaurants. The bills were $124, $48 and $268.

To tip the waiter a fair amount, John created a simple tip calculator (as a function). He likes to tip 20% of the bill when the bill is less than $50, 15% when the bill is between $50 and $200, and 10% if the bill is more than $200.

In the end, John would like to have 2 arrays:

1) Containing all three tips (one for each bill)
2) Containing all three final paid amounts (bill + tip).

**The issue that I am having is that my finalAmounts array is returning the concatenated values instead of the desired sum of the billAmounts + tips to result in the following: **

Total Amount Paid: 12418.6, 489.60, 26826.80

*My desired results would of course be: 142.6, 47.60, and 294.80*

Here is my code:

```
var billAmounts = [
    124,
    48,
    268
];

function tipCaluclator(bill) {
    if (bill < 50) {
        percentage = (20/100);
    } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200) {
        percentage = (15/100);
    } else { 
        percentage = (10/100);
    }
    var tip = percentage * bill;
    //return tip amount to 2 decimal places
    return tip.toFixed(2);
};=

var tips = [
    tipCaluclator(billAmounts[0]),
    tipCaluclator(billAmounts[1]),
    tipCaluclator(billAmounts[2])
];
console.log('These are the tip amounts: ', tips)

var finalAmounts = [
    billAmounts[0] + tips[0],
    billAmounts[1] + tips[1],
    billAmounts[2] + tips[2]
];
console.log('These are the full amounts: ', finalAmounts);
```

Comment: When you call `Number.toFixed()` you're converting the type to `string` - best practice is to apply formatting *after* you've finished performing any calculations.

Comment: My hunch was that may have been the issue but wasn't sure how to create the effect of two decimal places without it. I've since created a new array with the tips array and toFixed method and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return tip.toFixed(2);` changes the number to a string, which is why the values are concatenated.

You could just calculate the amounts first and then when you display the amounts then convert to two decimal places. Or you could use `parseFloat()` after using `toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 0):

The numbers inserted as strings to the array, and it's fine if this is what you want, but you should do two things:
 1. with the parseFloat you need to convert it first to decimals - so that the strings won't concat instead of sum together.
 2. after, you can use the map method to use on each number you got the toFixed(2) method in order to get 142.60 and not 142.6 (on each of the numbers). after this, it will return to the array as strings like the tips array

Hope this is helping ( :

```js
var billAmounts = [
    124,
    48,
    268
];

function tipCaluclator(bill) {
    if (bill < 50) {
        percentage = (20/100);
    } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200) {
        percentage = (15/100);
    } else { 
        percentage = (10/100);
    }
    var tip = percentage * bill;
    //return tip amount to 2 decimal places
    return tip.toFixed(2);
};

var tips = [
    tipCaluclator(billAmounts[0]),
    tipCaluclator(billAmounts[1]),
    tipCaluclator(billAmounts[2])
];
console.log('These are the tip amounts: ', tips)

var finalAmounts = [
    parseFloat(billAmounts[0]) + parseFloat(tips[0]),
    parseFloat(billAmounts[1]) + parseFloat(tips[1]),
    parseFloat(billAmounts[2]) + parseFloat(tips[2])
];

finalAmounts = finalAmounts.map(function(elem){
 return parseFloat(elem).toFixed(2)
})

console.log('These are the full amounts: ', finalAmounts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two main tips:

1. Remove `;=` after the `tipCaluclator` function.
2. Avoid doing the `.toFixed(2)` calls until you go to output the values. These actually become strings - they are no longer numbers to use in your other calculations. With some other, more minor code updates, here's an example of working code (as far as I understand your task, at least):

```js
const billAmounts = [
  124,
  48,
  268,
]

const numbersToCurrencyStrings = nums => nums.map(num => `$${num.toFixed(2)}`)

const tipCalculator = (bill) => {
  if (bill < 50) {
    return bill * .2
  } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200) {
    return bill * .15
  }
  return bill * .1
}

// Calculate tips
const tips = billAmounts.map(tipCalculator)
console.log('These are the tip amounts: ', numbersToCurrencyStrings(tips))

// Add matching tips to bills
const finalAmounts = billAmounts.map((bill, idx) => bill + tips[idx])
console.log('These are the full amounts: ', numbersToCurrencyStrings(finalAmounts))
```